# Do I need a backend for a gallery react app?

Tags: reactjs, database, amazon-web-services, web, backend

Recently I've been working on a website for an artist. I created the site with react.
I hosted the website using AWS Amplify - so I uploaded the site as a repository and created a website of it.

Now everything is working ok, except that the website is a little bit slow (maybe more than a little bit). There are a lot of images on the website which slows it down.

I did not created a backend or uploaded the images of the website to a separate database because I don't need authentication in the website (no e-commerce/users, just portfolio)

Do you think I should create a backend ?
Will that make the website load faster?

Comment: Not really. If its just about images and not that private you can create json to store those images url.

Comment: @vnm so, I can store the images somewhere on AWS and it should work faster ? (faster than when the images are on github)
And could it be that it is slow also because I'm not using CloudFront and the servers are far away from my location?

Comment: You can store images on s3 bucket and keep it public so you can access those public url in your app. You just need to create json file to store those public url and import it wherever required in your app. And about load time it depends on various factor. Better you optimise those images before storing on aws.